# jquery datatables fnfilter + script performace

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datatables

I am away from my development workstation so I thought I'd ask this in hopes of getting an answer when I try it tomorrow. I have a two part question relating to a web application i built using c# jquery and jquery datatables:

1) I know that we can set the value of fnfilter as metioned on their page using something like:

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

/* Filter immediately */
oTable.fnFilter( 'test string' );
} );
```

however is there a way to retrieve the value entered by the use in the search bar? I was thinking along the lines of
    var aContainer= oTable.fnFilter() 
or
    var aContainer= oTable.fnFilter($(this).html())

2) My application has to retrieve values from another source on the web. These are the value displayed in the datatable. Most of my processing(counting, etc..) is done client side and has drastically slowed down generating the web app. Does anyone know of any suggestions to increase performance of client side scripts specifically datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your datatable is really instantiated as `oTable = $('#example').dataTable();` then doing this:

```
var textEntered = $('#example_filter input:text')[0].value;
```

Should return whatever the user entered on the field for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to #1, you can get the value of the text entered into the search box by doing

```
// Assume the table's id attribute is 'blah'
var search_string = $('#blah_filter>input').val();
```

As far as #2, have you considered server-side processing of the data and sending the result to the client?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tarek. I'll try it out. I was trying to avoid writing server side code for simplicity but I might have to. Once again Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JQuery-DataTables-MVC.aspx)
 might give you a big help if you decide to write server side code. Now researching it myself (and not looking forward to implementing custom filtering!).